# Update an attribute of the Active Record using a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an **ActiveRecord** named `Station`. I want to update some attributes not directly, but using a variable.
Something like:

`station = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...")
 station.update_attributes(attr1: "...", attr2: "...", ..)`

But when I initialize the `station` variable I get **ActiveRecord::Relation**, which doesn't have the  `update_attributes` helper. How can i then update some fields of my `Station` using a variable, but not directly ?

Comment: You can use `update_all` on relation.  Have you tried this? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ActiveRecord#find_by` for this goal:

```
station = Station.find_by(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...") # Station first instance with specified attributes
station.update_attributes(attr1: "...", attr2: "...", ..)
```

This method returns `Station` instance if it exists with your attributes or `nil` in other case.

If you want find **all** `Station` instances and update **each**, you should use `ActiveRecord#update_all` method:

```
stations = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...") #ActiveRecord::Relation
stations.update_all(attr1: "new_attr1" , attr2: "new_attr_2")
```

Answer (score 2):

This code `station = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...")` will return a array of results

You cannot use `update_attributes` for array

so change your code

```
station = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...")

 station.update_attributes(attr1: "...", attr2: "...", ..)
```

to

```
station = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...")

station.update_all(attr1: "...", attr2: "...", ..)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `station` is a group, not a single.  So, call it `stations` to avoid confusion.

```
stations = Station.where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...")
new_values = my_get_new_vals(stations)
stations.each_with_index do |station, idx|
  station.update_attributes(new_values[idx])
end
```

If you want to set all the data to be the same, then you can say

```
Station.
  where(attr1: "..." , attr2: "...").
  update_all(
    :payment_total => 20,
    :due_amount => 10,
    :data => clonedata.to_json)
```

You need to think about where the data is coming from for these updates, and how to associate it with each object among what you found that needs updated.